# Remove leading zeros of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where I need to remove any leading zeros from a string
like `02-03`, `02&03`, `02`,`03`. I have this regex( `s.replace(/^0+/, '');` ) to remove leading zeros but I need something which works for the above cases.

```js
let strings = [`02-03`, `02&03`, `02`,`03`]
strings.forEach(s => {
  s = s.replace(/^0+/, '');
  console.log(s)
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sMgSp/94/ -- i have this fiddle to test with.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to use a word boundary (`\b`) like this:

```
s.replace(/\b0+/g, '')
```

This will remove any zeros that are not preceded by Latin letters, decimal digits, underscores. The global (`g`) flag is used to replace multiple matches (without that it would only replace the first match found).

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var s = $("input").val();
  
  s = s.replace(/\b0+/g, '');
  
  $("#out").text(s);
});
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
div { padding: .5em 0; }
#out { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input value="02-03, 02&03, 02,03"><button>Go</button></div>
<div>Output: <span id="out"></span></div>
```

Comment: does not work for decimals. F.e. for "0.5" returns ".5" which is not desired

Comment: @Glogo well that wasn't part of the original requirements, but if that's necessary for your use case, you can use `s.replace(/\b0+(0\.\d+)/g, '$1')` to handle decimals, or `s.replace(/\b(?:0*(0\.\d+)|0+)/g, '$1')` to handle decimals *or* integers (note it requires a leading zero be present to recognize the decimal, e.g `.005` will be treated as an integer).

Comment: It stripes zeros also from the decimal part :( e.g. '0030.005' returns '30.5'

Answer (score 2):

```
s.replace(/\b0+[1-9]\d*/g, '')
```

should replace any zeros that are after a word boundary and before a non-zero digit.  That is what I think you're looking for here.

Comment: Okay it compiles now, but it will only match numbers with at least 3 digits (so `02` won't be affected) and it will remove the entire number, not just the leading zeros.